# Finding arc length

Tags: trigonometry

How can you find the length of the arc formed by two points on a circle? Is there any function that draws a perfect semi-circle so you can use integrals to find the value of the arc or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know the angle formed by those two points and the center of the circle?  If so, and that angle is $\theta$ in radians, and the radius of the circle is $r$, then the arc length is $$ s = r \theta.$$

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_%28geometry%29).

Edited:

If you don't know $\theta$, you can find it by taking the dot product of the vectors from the center to each point.  More on the dot product [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: No, the angle is what I need to find. I know the radius however.

Comment: @Paul What *do* you know about the points?  Their coordinates, or something else?

Comment: Their coordinates and the radius of the circle.

Comment: @Paul So, is my addition helpful?

Comment: Yes, thank you! :)